# Mathematical notation for dropout mask

Tags: matrices, notation, python

I have this simple code:

```
D = np.random.rand(X.shape) # Create array of given shape with [0,1] bound random floats

D = ( D < k ) # Get boolean values from evaluation against [0,1] bound constant k
```

I would like to write this with the corresponding mathematical notations.

I believe a random number within [0,1] would be:

$$x\in\Bbb R:0\leq x\leq1$$

Although I have no clue how to feed a matrix of given shape from this.

For the conditional test, there may be:

$$x < k \rightarrow 0$$
$$x \geq k \rightarrow 1$$

Still, I have no clue how to deal with a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first matrix, something like this: Let $D$ be a matrix of the same dimensions as $X$ (or more likely, if $X$ is already known to be $m\times n$, "Let $D$ be an $m\times n$ matrix"), where the entries are iid random variables uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. You can also write this as $d_{ij}\sim\mathcal U(0,1)$.

For the second: Let $D'$ be the $m\times n$ matrix with entries
$$
d_{ij}' = 1_{[d_{ij} < k]},
$$
where $d_{ij}$ are the entries of $D$ and $1_{[\cdot]}$ is the indicator function. This is equivalent to your version with the cases, but you would normally write the cases like this:
$$
d_{ij}' = \begin{cases}1&d_{ij} < k\\0&d_{ij} \ge k. \end{cases}
$$

If you don't care about $D$ but only $D'$, you can say that the entries of $D'$ are independent Bernoulli distributed variables with parameter $k$, or $d_{ij}'\sim\mathcal Bern(k)$. (And don't define $D$ at all).

Comment: This is a great answer. Itself I don't care about D, but I try to replicate the code in maths line by line, so I would need to define D if I understand. "Let D be an m×n matrix" seems totally fine, I'd just ask if there is any way to define D without using natural language at all? Otherwise I'll write it as you did :)

Comment: I don't think you should avoid natural language, but you can say $D\in M^{m\times n}$. My problem with this is that $M^{m\times n}$ isn't a set, but it's a common enough notation anyway. You also need to say that the entries are independent (part of the "iid"), which you could choose to write as $d_{ij}\perp \!\! \perp d_{kl}$ for all $(i,j)\ne(k,l)$ – if you *really* want to.

Comment: I will then not avoid natural language, many thanks for the explanations :)

Comment: @Synthase I made a small edit showing how you could write cases instead of using an indicator function (though I recommend the latter). An important point is that things in maths are commonly defined with $=$ or $:=$, but not with $\rightarrow$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\{ A \}\ {\rm s.t.}\ A \in {\bf M}^{n \times m}, m_{ij} = \sim {\cal B}[\theta]$$

The set of matrices $A$ in the set of $n \times m$ matrices in which every component is chosen from the Bernoulli distribution with parameter (threshold) $\theta$.

Comment: Rather than defining a set, I would say “let $D$ be a $m\times n$ matrix where the entries are …” (or similar) fits OP better